# ANSI colors working in Git Bash EXCEPT for 'php artisan' commands

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, git-bash, laravel-artisan

I'm on Windows 10 Pro 64bit. New AMD Ryzen system. And I've got a weird issue.

ANSI colors work fine for everything except Laravel commands. Any ideas anyone?

[image: Git Bash showing Laravel Help command displaying ANSI chars]

Comment: FYI - I use Windows 10 powershell - never had an Ascii issues with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up upgrading Laravel from 5.2 to 5.4 and it fixed it... We'll see what other bugs this has caused lol. But I was going to upgrade at some point anyway.

Thanks a lot for the responses! Helped me think about a different perspective!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a character encoding issues.

Did you save your file as utf8? Or did you use special characters? If you copy paste your commands from somewhere; first past them in Notepad, then select all, copy content, and past again in your project.

Comment: 1 solution; Upload artisan.php, with an FTP client to a server and make SURE you set 'transport' to plain/text/ascii. Download artisan.php again.

Comment: No copy pasting or outputting from file. Even if I simply run `php artisan --version`, I get that issue. Only happens with `php artisan` commands. `composer`, `git`, and `bash` commands have nice colors instead of ANSI codes. EDIT: arisan.php? interesting. I'll look into it now!

Comment: Do you have your windows machine on somekind of foreign language?. Yeah the encoding of artisan.php is f#cked up somehow. You can also just download the 'raw' version of artisan.php here; https://github.com/laravel/framework  just replace the file could also fix it.